# Error while deploying my dapp to icp network

Tags: http, deployment, internet-computer

IC0302: Canister f3l4q-2qaaa-aaaal-qdh6a-cai has no query method 'http_request'.May i know how this can be resolved

I want to deploy my canister id dbank_frontend to the icp network.I had consumed free cycles deployed my app to the icp and i had left with 3.8222 Trillion cycles.When i am able to get my dbank_frontend canister id after deployment and paste into the url browser with the url:https://f3l4q-2qaaa-aaaal-qdh6a-cai.ic0.io i had ended up with the above error.May i know how to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

Sharing your source code and steps to reproduce the issue would greatly help to identify the root cause of the error.

Alternatively, you could use one of the examples in the language of your choice and incrementally develop from there: https://internetcomputer.org/docs/current/home